# Select the record with the latest date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these entries in my SQL:

```
Reference    | Clearing Date | Posting Date | Payment Date
LVR181035902 | 2018-11-23    | 2017-12-23   | 2018-10-23
LVR181035902 | 2018-11-28    | 2018-11-23   | 2018-08-23
LVR181035902 | 2018-11-23    | 2017-12-23   | 2018-10-23
```

And I want to return the entry with the latest `Clearing Date`, so my result will be:

```
Reference    | Clearing Date | Posting Date | Payment Date
LVR181035902 | 2018-11-28    | 2018-11-23   | 2018-08-23
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT reference, clearing_date= max(clearing_date) FROM trdinvoices WHERE reference='LVR181035902' GROUP BY reference
```

which will return:

```
[
    {
        "reference": "LVR181035902",
        "clearing_date": "2018-11-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

But I want the result to return the whole line like this:

```
[
    {
        "reference": "LVR181035902",
        "clearing_date": "2018-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "posting_date": "2018-11-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "payment_date": "2018-08-23T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

How can I do this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can sort data according to 'Clearing Date' in descending order, and can return the result set:

```
  -- sqlserver
Select Top 1 * From dbo.Table Order By ClearingDate Desc;
 -- if you want to select a particular row based on a key
Select Top 1 * From dbo.Table Where Reference = 'LVR181035902' Order By ClearingDate Desc;

-- add 'Limit' for MySQL
```

Comment: I need to include `WHERE reference='LVR181035902'` because I have thousands of entries, not only those 3.

Comment: I tried this `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM trdinvoices WHERE trdinvoices.reference="LVR181035902" ORDER BY clearing_date asc` but it's not working, I get `"Invalid column name 'LVR181035902'."`

Comment: @Tenzolinho you need to use `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM trdinvoices WHERE trdinvoices.reference='LVR181035902' `. This solution is definitely better than the accepted one ;)

Comment: @Tenzolinho yes! you are definitely right on the contest! i edited my answer over there!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach of doing it.

```
SELECT reference, 
       clearing_date, 
       posting_date, 
       payment_date 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER(partition BY reference 
                   ORDER BY clearing_date DESC) rn 
        FROM   trdinvoices 
        WHERE  reference = 'LVR181035902') t 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but you have any idea why do I get `Invalid column name 'LVR181035902'`?

Comment: I don't know what happened, after some tries I managed to run the query. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

another way  `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by reference order by clearing_date desc)rn
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select reference, clearing_date=max(clearing_date), posting_date, payment_date from trdinvoices Group By reference, posting_date, payment_date having reference = 'LVR181035902'
```

Use Above query.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but you have any idea why do I get `Invalid column name 'LVR181035902'`?

Comment: Can you send query for check Invalid column name issue? or please match your table columns to check each column name is correct or not in your query.

Answer (score 0):

A method with good performance uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.clearing_date = (select max(t2.clearing_date) from t t2 where t2.reference = t.reference);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(reference, clearing_date)`.